# python delete elements that match critera from a list -

Tags: python

I want to remove Names and Fees for those that have not paid

```
Names = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
Fees = ["n","y","y","y","n","y"]

print("Names:",Names)
print("Fees paid:",Fees)

for i in range (0,len(Fees)):
    if Fees[i] == "n":
        del(Names[i])
        del(Fees[i])

print("Names:",Names)
print("Fees paid:",Fees)
```

Comment: It's generally poor design to use multiple lists like this. Use a list of tuples or dictionaries so the related data is kept together.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is going on with your code? Is it erroring? Printing unexpected values? If so, what is the expected output? Have you tried stepping through with a debugger and seeing if any values are different than expected?

Comment: Try this `out = [name for name, fee in zip(Names, Fees) if fee != 'n']`

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the code:

1. When you delete an element, all the following indexes move down, and you'll skip the next element when `i` increments.
2. The `range` goes to the original list length. After you delete elements, the later indexes will be invalid so you'll get an `IndexError`.

Instead of modifying the original lists in place, append to new lists.

```
new_names = []
new_fees = []
for name, fee in zip(Names, Fees):
    if fee != 'n':
        new_names.append(name)
        new_fees.append(fee)

Names = new_names
Fees = new_fees
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to delete items *in place* you're better off looping backwards:

```
for i in range (len(Fees)-1,-1,-1):
    if Fees[i] == "n":
        del(Names[i])
        del(Fees[i])
```

Another possibility is to create a new list via a list comprehension:

```
new_names = [n for i,n in enumerate(Names) if Fees[i] == 'y']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

> Make an iterator that filters elements from data returning only those that have a corresponding element in selectors that evaluates to True. Stops when either the data or selectors iterables has been exhausted.

We use this to retain only the names of people who have paid their fees:

```py
from itertools import compress

names = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
fees = ["n","y","y","y","n","y"]

list(compress(names, map(lambda x: x != "n", fees)))
```

This outputs:

```py
['b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback.  I think if I replace the element with "" I might be ok. I'm trying to complete the task at a GCSE student level.